# Firebaseのログイン／登録の際のエラーメッセージ

Tags: firebase

サーバーから返ってくるエラーメッセージだけど
例）https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#signInWithCredential

こちらはサーバーから英語でしか来ないみたいですが、日本語でこのエラーメッセージを表示する機能ございますでしょうか。

それとも、Client側で全部自分で翻訳して設定するしかありませんか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

はい、現状ドキュメントや使っていて把握する限り エラーメッセージの言語切替はサポートされていません。
Error Codeを見て対応するメッセージを自分で用意する必要があります。

Comment: ありがとうございました。
早く日本語にも対応するといいですね！！

Comment: 私はそんなに必要性を感じてませんがサポートに問い合わせてみるのは１つの手かもしれません。要望は伝えておいたほうがいいですね。たぶん日本語でも汲み取ってくれると思います。

https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/

Comment: 「メールアドレスが既に使用されている」「パスワードが弱すぎる」とかのエラーメッセージは誰でもしょっちゅう必要だと思いますので！このエラーは日本語あったらいいなと思って！